# Cannot use .Any() to check whether linq return emty

Tags: c#, linq

I have these lines of code:

```
var check = (from search in db.CartItems
             where search.ItemID == ID && search.CartID == UCart.ID
             select search);
```

and when I want to check if the query return empty I use:

```
if (!check.Any())
```

but it throws error:

> '!check.Any()' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

I check around but it seems that everyone is fine with `Any()` except me. I have checked using `FirstOrDefault()` but still got the same error.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: I bet your db.CartItems is null

Comment: @Mike_G Yes it is empty. I created that table in sql but didnt add any row into it. So does it cause any problem here?

Comment: The issue is not with `Any`, the issue is something in your query attempts to access a member of a `null` reference. The obvious candidates here are `db`, `db.CartItems` and `UCart`.

Comment: Actually I'm guessing that `db` is `null`.

Comment: @CharlesMager I got it.
My UCart is null because I'm checking a part of my code so it didn't define UCart. Thank you